# Beaglebone black LCD4 and PWM

Tags: beagleboneblack, lcd, pwm

I have a BBB running Debian Jessie. I have a modified LCD4 cape that runs great. My LCD cape uses EHRPWM1A. I would like to use the PWM output of EHRPWM1B. It is going to attach to a piezo buzzer.

I know that I can use the PWM output when my LCD cape is not enabled. I have modified the BB-BONE-BACONE cape to create 2 PWM outputs. I know that it is possible to control both the backlight for the LCD as well as the PWM for the buzzer simultaneously.

With my LCD cape enabled, I can export the PWM channel for my buzzer, set my period and duty cycle, but I get no output. Anybody have any thoughts about why this is?

My guess is that I don't understand something about how the /sys/class/backlight interacts with the PWM, but I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to get this working by compiling the PWM into the overlay.

For anyone interested in this in the future, I've posted the overlay I used below.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

#include <dt-bindings/board/am335x-bbw-bbb-base.h>
#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>
#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/am33xx.h>

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black", "ti,beaglebone-green";

    /* identification */
    part-number = "BB-BONE-LCD4-01";
    version = "00A2";

    /* state the resources this cape uses */
    exclusive-use =
        /* the pin header uses */
        "P8.45",    /* lcd: lcd_data0 */
        "P8.46",    /* lcd: lcd_data1 */
        "P8.43",    /* lcd: lcd_data2 */
        "P8.44",    /* lcd: lcd_data3 */
        "P8.41",    /* lcd: lcd_data4 */
        "P8.42",    /* lcd: lcd_data5 */
        "P8.39",    /* lcd: lcd_data6 */
        "P8.40",    /* lcd: lcd_data7 */
        "P8.37",    /* lcd: lcd_data8 */
        "P8.38",    /* lcd: lcd_data9 */
        "P8.36",    /* lcd: lcd_data10 */
        "P8.34",    /* lcd: lcd_data11 */
        "P8.35",    /* lcd: lcd_data12 */
        "P8.33",    /* lcd: lcd_data13 */
        "P8.31",    /* lcd: lcd_data14 */
        "P8.32",    /* lcd: lcd_data15 */
        "P8.27",    /* lcd: lcd_vsync */
        "P8.29",    /* lcd: lcd_hsync */
        "P8.28",    /* lcd: lcd_pclk */
        "P8.30",    /* lcd: lcd_ac_bias_en */
        "P9.16",    /* buzzer pin   */
        "ehrpwm1a",
        "ehrpwm1b",
        "lcdc",
        "tscadc";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {


            bb_lcd_pwm_backlight_pins: pinmux_bb_lcd_pwm_backlight_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    BONE_P9_14 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE6) /* gpmc_a2.ehrpwm1a */
                    BONE_P9_16 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE6) /* gpmc_a2.ehrpwm1a */
                >;
            };

            bb_lcd_lcd_pins: pinmux_bb_lcd_lcd_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    BONE_P9_27 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7) /* mcasp0_fsr.gpio3_19 */

                    BONE_P8_45 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data0.lcd_data0 */
                    BONE_P8_46 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data1.lcd_data1 */
                    BONE_P8_43 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data2.lcd_data2 */
                    BONE_P8_44 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data3.lcd_data3 */
                    BONE_P8_41 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data4.lcd_data4 */
                    BONE_P8_42 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data5.lcd_data5 */
                    BONE_P8_39 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data6.lcd_data6 */
                    BONE_P8_40 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data7.lcd_data7 */
                    BONE_P8_37 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data8.lcd_data8 */
                    BONE_P8_38 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data9.lcd_data9 */
                    BONE_P8_36 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data10.lcd_data10 */
                    BONE_P8_34 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data11.lcd_data11 */
                    BONE_P8_35 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data12.lcd_data12 */
                    BONE_P8_33 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data13.lcd_data13 */
                    BONE_P8_31 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data14.lcd_data14 */
                    BONE_P8_32 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_data15.lcd_data15 */

                    BONE_P8_27 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_vsync.lcd_vsync */
                    BONE_P8_29 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_hsync.lcd_hsync */
                    BONE_P8_28 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_pclk.lcd_pclk */
                    BONE_P8_30 (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* lcd_ac_bias_en.lcd_ac_bias_en */
                >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&epwmss1>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&ehrpwm1>;
        __overlay__ {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&bb_lcd_pwm_backlight_pins>;
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@3 {
        target = <&lcdc>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@4 {
        target = <&tscadc>;
        __overlay__ {

            status = "okay";
            tsc {
                ti,wires = <4>;
                ti,x-plate-resistance = <200>;
                ti,coordinate-readouts = <5>;
                ti,wire-config = <0x00 0x11 0x22 0x33>;
            };

            adc {
                ti,adc-channels = <4 5 6 7>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@5 {
        target-path="/";
        __overlay__ {

            /* avoid stupid warning */
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;

            backlight {
                status = "okay";
                compatible = "pwm-backlight";
                pwms = <&ehrpwm1 0 250000 0>;
                brightness-levels = <
                    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
                    10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
                    20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                    30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
                    40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
                    50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
                    60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
                    70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
                    80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
                    90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
                    100
                >;
                default-brightness-level = <100>;
            };

            panel {
                status = "okay";
                compatible = "ti,tilcdc,panel";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&bb_lcd_lcd_pins>;
                panel-info {
                    ac-bias           = <255>;
                    ac-bias-intrpt    = <0>;
                    dma-burst-sz      = <16>;
                    bpp               = <16>;
                    fdd               = <0x80>;
                    sync-edge         = <0>;
                    sync-ctrl         = <1>;
                    raster-order      = <0>;
                    fifo-th           = <0>;
                };
                display-timings {
                    native-mode = <&timing0>;
                    /* www.newhavendisplay.com/app_notes/OTA5180A.pdf */
                    timing0: 480x272 {
                        clock-frequency = <9200000>;
                        hactive = <480>;
                        vactive = <272>;
                        hfront-porch = <8>;
                        hback-porch = <47>;
                        hsync-len = <41>;
                        vback-porch = <2>;
                        vfront-porch = <3>;
                        vsync-len = <10>;
                        hsync-active = <0>;
                        vsync-active = <0>;
                        de-active = <1>;
                        pixelclk-active = <0>;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

For PWM control, use the following commands:

```
sudo su //or log in as root
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/export //export PWM to userspace
cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm1 //change directories to make things a bit easier
echo 250000 > period //NOTE: this number must match the frequency used for the LCD backlight
echo 125000 > duty_cycle //set our duty cycle of the PWM in nano seconds
echo 1 > enable //turn PWM on
echo 0 > enable //turn PWM off
```

Hope this helps other people.